# How can I make my carrot cake taste more carroty

Tags: baking, flavor, cake, carrots

I have used organic carrots finely grated and increased the quantity of carrots used, but still can't taste the carrot

Comment: You should be aware that carrot cake tends to taste sweet, rich and even spicy, but is not typically very *carroty*.  Its more just complexly aromatic, with the carrot being one element of that.

Comment: The whole idea of carrot cake is not to taste carroty, but to keep you mum happy that your are having your vegetables

Comment: I think both these points are somewhat moot. 'Ours is not to reason why...' etc.

Answer (score 4):

You could try a few different tactics:

- **Use some roasted carrots.** Roasting intensifies the flavour by removing water. Try not to brown them too much though, which will give them a burnt-sugar taste.
- **Use complimentary spices.** Mace, which is the dried membrane that surrounds nutmeg, compliments and enhances the flavour of carrots very well. If you can't find mace, try nutmeg itself.
- **Reduce carrot juice.** Simmer until syrupy and add to the cake. You might need a little more flour to compensate for the extra liquid.

Answer (score 3):

You're not the only person experiencing this issue, there are reports that over the last few decades carrots have been [losing nutrition](http://www.carrotmuseum.co.uk/nutrition.html) and by extension, taste.

Here are some decisive things you can do to get more and more pleasant carrot taste of your carrots:

- Get the **largest carrots** you can (the more tasty part of carrots is the outer and lower part, bigger carrots have more of it).
- **Use the bottom two thirds** for your recipe (and save the top part for another dish).
- Buy **purple or other colour carrots**.  Apparently, the orange carrot was selectively [bred and domesticated by the Dutch Royalty](http://www.carrotmuseum.co.uk/history5.html).  You may find all kinds of neat flavours in other types of carrots.
- Try the **Mukum Carrot variety**, they generally sweeter and may show up as more carroty ;)
- Carrots from **colder climates are sweeter**, particularly when temperatures go below freezing (the carrot plant makes sugar to prevent freezing and self preserve).  See this [document from Chef Dan Barber](http://www.bluehillfarm.com/sites/default/files/08.pdf) of the world-class Blue Hill restaurant.

The details what were the sweet and bitter **taste of Organic Carrots come from** are in [this document](http://www.carrotmuseum.co.uk/Sweet%20and%20Bitter%20Taste%20in%20Organic%20Carrots.pdf).

Comment: I'm starting to see more heirloom carrots at farm stands in my area (Maryland / DC Metro) ... but I haven't seen the huge 'winter carrots' that we used to get in the Netherlands.

Comment: I find it strange that you propose large carrots. In my personal experience, the larger a carrot, the woodier. The youngest, tiniest carrots are much sweeter and have more aroma too.

Comment: @rumtscho yes, counter intuitive.  We first noticed this a couple of years and the carrot museum also implies it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go fancy, you could do an agar-agar carrot extraction and soak your finished cake with the carrot extract. http://www.instructables.com/id/How-To-GelatinAgar-Filtration/